# JCheckBox with Image

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon, jcheckbox

How can I have a checkbox group with an image?

I use:

```
for (String testata : listaTestate) {
        JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
        ImageIcon imgTestata = new ImageIcon("src/img/"+testata+".png");
        checkbox.setName(testata);
        checkbox.setBackground(new Color(194, 169, 221));
        checkbox.setSelected(true);
        testate.add(checkbox);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(imgTestata);
        label.setBackground(new Color(194, 169, 221));
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        testate.add(label);
    }
```

but there is a lot of space between the ImageIcon and the JCheckBox.

Comment: Don't use `src/img/...`, `src` won't exist once the problem is deployed.  Use `getClass().getResource("/img/...")` instead

Comment: Do you want each check box to have an image or just the group?

Comment: Each ceckboh have a different image (based on the String testata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the layout manager, it's difficult to be 100%, but if I was doing this, I might use a `GridBagLayout`...

```
testate.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
for (String testata : listaTestate) {
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    ImageIcon imgTestata = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+testata+".png"));
    checkbox.setName(testata);
    checkbox.setBackground(new Color(194, 169, 221));
    checkbox.setSelected(true);
    testate.add(checkbox, gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    JLabel label = new JLabel(imgTestata);
    label.setBackground(new Color(194, 169, 221));
    testate.add(label, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
}
```

You may also like to have a read through:

- [Retrieving Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html)
- [Location-Independent Access to Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)
- [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)
- [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 0):

the space happens because you call `.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));` on each label instance created on your loop,which resulting wide label, so remove it and the result will just fine.

Comment: oh ya and calling .getClass().getResource() is preferred , just like @MadProgrammer said it to you.

Comment: without label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50)); I have the same problem.  :(

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: @Razzo, it must be it, because I tested your code also. When remove it the space between checkbox & icon is dissappeared, or perhaps you use some layouts to manages the space like GridLayout maybe..